# Saving vertical space in tree diagram

Tags: diagrams, trees, forest

I have many nodes on one tier. Thus I use the grow east option already. But this is not enough... I would like to save a bit more vertical space for instance through pulling two of the branches a little bit to the right. Or maybe pulling out the middle one would look even better...

Is there an option for extending the horizontal lines? Or does someone has a different idea how to save vertical space excep reducing the size? :)

[image: big tree]

Here my code:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

%Defining tikz classes for tree diagrams
\tikzset{parent/.style={align=center,text width=3cm,rounded corners=3pt},
    child/.style={align=center,text width=3cm,rounded corners=3pt}
    }

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \resizebox{.7\textwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{forest}
                for tree={
                    grow'=east,
                    forked edges,
                    draw,
                    rounded corners,
                    node options={
                        align=center },
                    text width=2.7cm,
                    anchor=west,
                }
                [LMS, fill=gray!25, parent
                [Funktionale \\Anforderungen, for tree={fill=brown!25, child}
                [Lerninhalte organisieren]
                [Lerninhalte erstellen]
                [Lerninhalte abfragen]
                [Kommunikation]
                [Benutzerkonten\-führung]
                [Steuerungs\-funktionen]
                ]
                [Nicht-Funktionale Anforderungen, for tree={fill=red!25,child}
                [Zuverl{\"a}ssig\-keit]
                [Skalierbar\-keit und Effizienz]
                [Benutzer\-freundlich\-keit]
                [Portierbarkeit]
                [Datenschutz / Informationssicherheit]
                [Erweiterbar\-keit]
                [Anpassbarkeit]
                ]
                [Technische Rahmen\-bedinungen, for tree={fill=blue!25, child}
                [System\-architektur]
                [Software\-kriterien]
                [Schnittstellen]
                [Wartung und Support
                [Support\-leistungen]
                [Software-Pflege]
                ]
                ]     
                ]
            \end{forest}    
        }
    \end{center}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if this is helpful but, as a follow up to discussion in comments, you might make the tree more generally compact by doing something like this:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\tikzset{%
  parent/.style={align=center,text width=3cm,rounded corners=3pt},
  child/.style={align=center,text width=3cm,rounded corners=3pt}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \resizebox{.7\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{forest}
      for tree={
        % forked edges,
        draw,
        rounded corners,
        node options={align=center,},
        text width=2.7cm,
      },
      where level=0{%
      }{%
        folder,
        grow'=0,
        if level=1{%
          before typesetting nodes={child anchor=north},
          edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-5pt) -| (.child anchor)},
        }{},
      }
      [LMS, fill=gray!25, parent
      [Funktionale \\Anforderungen, for tree={fill=brown!25, child}
      [Lerninhalte organisieren]
      [Lerninhalte erstellen]
      [Lerninhalte abfragen]
      [Kommunikation]
      [Benutzerkonten\-führung]
      [Steuerungs\-funktionen]
      ]
      [Nicht-Funktionale Anforderungen, for tree={fill=red!25,child}
      [Zuverl{\"a}ssig\-keit]
      [Skalierbar\-keit und Effizienz]
      [Benutzer\-freundlich\-keit]
      [Portierbarkeit]
      [Datenschutz / Informationssicherheit]
      [Erweiterbar\-keit]
      [Anpassbarkeit]
      ]
      [Technische Rahmen\-bedinungen, for tree={fill=blue!25, child}
      [System\-architektur]
      [Software\-kriterien]
      [Schnittstellen]
      [Wartung und Support
      [Support\-leistungen]
      [Software-Pflege]
      ]
      ]
      ]
    \end{forest}
  }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: compact tree]

Note that resizing graphics which contain text is not recommended as you end up with a motley of different font sizes. So, if you can avoid resizing the box like that, it would be preferable.

## EDIT

To address the queries in comments:

1. 'Centre' is actually ambiguous - centre relative to *what*? I would recommend aligning the root with the middle child. The easiest way to do this is probably to add `calign with current edge` to the relevant child node:

   ```
   [Nicht-Funktionale Anforderungen, for tree={fill=red!25,child}, calign with current edge
   ```

which gives

[image: align root]

The edges are being controlled in multiple ways:

- `forked edges` applies to the entire tree (although it is not actually doing anything as it is being overridden in all cases);
- `folder` changes the edges for all nodes below the root, which is to say, all nodes which can possibly have edges;
- `edge path'` then makes a final change for the nodes in the first level only, which are the edges you were trying to change.

So to revert to the default style for the first level, we want to:

- delete `forked edges`;
- delete `edge path`.

`folder` doesn't harm anything here, so we can just leave that:

[image: diagonals to level 1]

If we wanted the edges to begin from a common point, we could redefine `parent anchor` for the root:

```
  where level=0{%
    parent anchor=children,
  }{%
```

[image: diagonals from common point]

or we could use an alternative definition of `edge path` of whatever kind we wanted. For example:

```
  where level=0{%
    parent anchor=children,
  }{%
    folder,
    grow'=0,
    if level=1{%
      before typesetting nodes={child anchor=north},
      edge path'={%
        (!u.parent anchor) -- ++(0,-5pt) -- (.child anchor)
      },
    }{},
  }
```

[image: alternate edge path]

Comment: I really like this!

Comment: I got to correct myself, this is awesome!

Comment: @Eric I think `folder` is rather misleading as a name for this as it makes me think it is about what the nodes look like, rather than the structure of the tree. But it makes it *much* easier than it was to do this in version 1.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to center the root node?

Comment: I think I could make it with `calign=fixed edge angles, calign primary angle=-80,calign secondary angle=80,`. Please correct me if this is nonsense.

Comment: another point, just for my learning process: I tried to change the level0 to level1 connection directly (diagonal). Actually I thought this could be done by commenting out `forked edges` but it doesn't. Is there a quick trick?

Comment: @Eric Does this help? `forked edges` isn't actually doing anything, I don't think, so removing it makes no odds....

Comment: Thanks alot for your detailled explanation! This definitely makes much more clear. Just one thing regarding your first point to `calign with current edge`: I can't use this when I have an even number of nodes. Is there another easier way than the one I mentioned above by setting the angles?

Comment: @Eric I don't think so. If that works, that seems probably easiest. Or you can use `midpoint` but then you need to set the primary and secondary children appropriately, which might have other effects.

Answer (score 5):

You could align the nodes on the next level with `tier=<some name>`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[ngerman]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\tikzset{%
    ,parent/.style={align=center,text width=3cm,rounded corners=3pt}
    ,child/.style={align=center,text width=3cm,rounded corners=3pt}
    }

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}\centering
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={%
            ,scale=.78
            ,grow'=east
            ,forked edges
            ,draw
            ,rounded corners
            ,node options={align=center}
            ,text width=2.7cm
            ,anchor=west
            }
        [LMS, fill=gray!25, parent
            [Funktionale \\Anforderungen, tier=align here, for tree={fill=brown!25, child}
                [Lerninhalte organisieren]
                [Lerninhalte erstellen]
                [Lerninhalte abfragen]
                [Kommunikation]
                [Benutzerkonten\-führung]
                [Steuerungs\-funktionen]
            ]
            [Nicht-Funktionale Anforderungen, for tree={fill=red!25,child}
                [Zuverl{\"a}ssig\-keit]
                [Skalierbar\-keit und Effizienz]
                [Benutzer\-freundlich\-keit]
                [Portierbarkeit]
                [Datenschutz / Informationssicherheit]
                [Erweiterbar\-keit]
                [Anpassbarkeit, tier=align here]
            ]
            [Technische Rahmen\-bedinungen, tier=align here, for tree={fill=blue!25, child}
                [System\-architektur]
                [Software\-kriterien]
                [Schnittstellen]
                [Wartung und Support
                    [Support\-leistungen]
                    [Software-Pflege]
                ]
            ]     
        ]
    \end{forest}    
\end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that's quite an option. Is there also a way to align the branches surrounding the root node LMS?

Comment: @Eric Sorry, I do not understand. Do you want to get the two branches I just pushed down for one level to be pulled up two levels? This would need some reordering of the whole [[[]]] system which you could do by your self, I guess. You could align `Nicht-Funktionale Anforderungen` with e.g. `Steuerungsfunktionen` then. However it would be difficult to show that this is a tree then, if there is no growth to the right of LMS. Maybe you should redesign the whole thing to "top-down" or you get rid of the first level "LMS" and describe it in `\caption{Three childs of LMS}` or alike.

Comment: I mean is there a way to get rid of the grow east and archieve some space by positioning `Funktionale Anforderungen` on the upper left hand side of `LMS` and `Technische Rahmenbedingungen` on the lower left hand side of `LMS`. So `LMS` would be in the center, two branches on the left hand side and one on the right hand side, you know?

Comment: @Eric I'm not really clear what you mean. The children of Funk. Anf. would then end up growing down over Tech. Rah., wouldn't they? If you use something like TikZ trees, you can have cyclical growth, but Forest doesn't support that. You can't have e.g. one child growing north and another south if they are children of the same parent. (You can fake it using separate trees, but it requires manual adjustments.)

Comment: @Eric What about using the directory style offered by Forest now?

Comment: @cfr maybe I consider trying to archieve this with TikZ next time. For now I really like your suggestion below!