# saving horizontal space in tree diagram

Tags: diagrams, trees, forest

About a week ago @cfr already provided a very decent solution for [saving vertical space in my tree diagram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299170/saving-vertical-space-in-tree-diagram). Unfortunately my initial situation has changed now and I am facing a horizontal tree which exceeds my skills. Actually it is the same tree as in my previous question, with the difference that one of the three main branches is now part of the two remaining main branches. Here is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

%Defining tikz classes for tree diagrams
\tikzset{parent/.style={align=center,text width=3cm,rounded corners=3pt},
    child/.style={align=center,text width=3cm,rounded corners=3pt}
}

\colorlet{col1}{white}
\colorlet{col2}{gray!20}
\colorlet{col3}{gray!40}
\colorlet{col4}{gray!60}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
        \begin{forest}
            forked edges,
            for tree={
                draw,
                rounded corners,
                node options={align=center,},
                text width=2.7cm,
                minimum height=1.5cm,
                parent anchor=children,
            }
            [LMS, fill=col4, parent, s sep=3cm
            [Funktionale \\Anforderungen, for tree={child, fill=col3}
            [Lerninhalte organisieren, tier=first]
            [Lerninhalte erstellen]
            [Lerninhalte abfragen]
            [Kommunikation]
            [Benutzerkonten\-führung]
            [Steuerungs\-funktionen]
            ]
            [Nicht-Funktionale Anforderungen, tier=first, for tree={child, fill=col2}
            [Zuverl{\"a}ssig\-keit]
            [Skalierbar\-keit und Effizienz]
            [Benutzer\-freundlich\-keit]
            [Portierbarkeit]
            [Datenschutz / Informationssicherheit]
            [Erweiterbar\-keit]
            [Anpassbarkeit]
            [Technische Rahmen\-bedinungen, for tree={child, calign=last, fill=col1}
            [System\-architektur]
            [Software\-kriterien]
            [Schnittstellen]
            [Wartung und Support
            [Support\-leistungen]
            [Software-Pflege]
            ]
            ]
            ]
            ]
        \end{forest}
    }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: horizontal tree]

For some reasons the nodes with a linebreak doesn't align well... Can somebody explain why or rather how I can fix this?

And is there a way to split off only one node of one level? In the example the node "Technische Rahmenbedinungen" should be splitted to the right by 2cm. `s sep` just applies for an entire level...

Last but not least, has anyone an idea how to save even a bit more of horizontal space here? The text is still a little bit too small.

I also did this, which of course is quite a good alternative but the horizontal teases me:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,ngerman]{article}
    \usepackage[edges]{forest}
    \usepackage{caption}

    %Defining tikz classes for tree diagrams
    \tikzset{parent/.style={align=center,text width=3cm,rounded corners=3pt},
        child/.style={align=center,text width=3cm,rounded corners=3pt}
    }

    \colorlet{col1}{white}
    \colorlet{col2}{gray!20}
    \colorlet{col3}{gray!40}
    \colorlet{col4}{gray!60}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{center}
            \resizebox*{.75\linewidth}{!}{%
                \begin{forest}
                    forked edges,
                    for tree={
                        grow'=east,
                        draw,
                        rounded corners,
                        text width=2.7cm,
                        node options={align=center},
                    }       
                    [LMS, fill=col4, parent, s sep=1cm
                    [Funktionale \\Anforderungen, for tree={child, fill=col3}
                    [Lerninhalte organisieren]
                    [Lerninhalte erstellen]
                    [Lerninhalte abfragen, calign with current]
                    [Kommunikation]
                    [Benutzerkonten\-führung]
                    [Steuerungs\-funktionen]
                    ]
                    [Nicht-Funktionale Anforderungen, for tree={child, fill=col2}
                    [Zuverl{\"a}ssig\-keit]
                    [Skalierbar\-keit und Effizienz]
                    [Benutzer\-freundlich\-keit]
                    [Portierbarkeit]
                    [Datenschutz/\\Informations-\\sicherheit, calign with current]
                    [Erweiterbar\-keit]
                    [Anpassbarkeit]
                    [Technische Rahmen\-bedinungen, calign=last, for tree={child, fill=col1}
                    [System\-architektur]
                    [Software\-kriterien]
                    [Schnittstellen]
                    [Wartung und Support
                    [Support\-leistungen]
                    [Software-Pflege]
                    ]
                    ]
                    ]
                    ]
                \end{forest}}
                \captionsetup{type=figure}
                \captionof{figure}{Gliederung des UKSH Lastenheft: Subgliederung LMS}
                \label{abb:GliederungUKSHLMS}
            \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: vertical tree]

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Does the exact code I posted in my edit give you that result? Or only in your document? If the first, what version of Forest do you have? I'm using 2.0.2. If the second, try to add things into the minimal document to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I found the problem... I just added the class `my phantom` to `\tikzset`. After changing the classes definition as done by you to `\forestset` it works properly, sorry for this.

Comment: Oh. Yes, it needs to be under the `forest` path and not just a `tikz` style for this. No problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

```
anchor=parent,
```

for the tree will ensure that the nodes are aligned more neatly:

[image: neater alignment]

To move a particular node, you can add

```
before drawing tree={x'+=20mm}
```

for the node in question. For example:

[image: shift node right]

If you want it to apply to the node's descendants as well, you can add it for the entire sub-tree. For example:

```
[Technische Rahmen\-bedinungen, for tree={child, calign=last, fill=col1, before drawing tree={x'+=20mm}}
```

[image: shift sub-tree right]

Of course, this obviously uses more horizontal space in a tree which already looks as if it is spread rather uncomfortably. (*Why* does it need to go 2cm to the right? Whatever this represents, could it be represented in another way?)

It is hard to know what to suggest regarding the horizontal space. The most obvious suggestion is to not do the things you are doing to *increase* horizontal space, such as using a uniform `text width` even for nodes which do not require so much space. And setting `s sep=3cm` obviously increases the use of horizontal space further.

If you can sacrifice those constraints, you can do something like this:

[image: rearranged tree]

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
%Defining tikz classes for tree diagrams
\forestset{%
  parent/.style={text width=3cm,rounded corners=3pt},
  child/.style={rounded corners=3pt},
  my phantom/.style={inner xsep=0pt, draw=none, child anchor=children}
}
\colorlet{col1}{white}
\colorlet{col2}{gray!20}
\colorlet{col3}{gray!40}
\colorlet{col4}{gray!60}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    forked edges,
    for tree={
        draw,
        rounded corners,
        align=center,
        text centered,
        minimum height=1.5cm,
        parent anchor=children,
        anchor=parent,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      where n children=0{}{%
        if content={}{}{%
          text width=27mm
        },
      },
    },
    [LMS, fill=col4, parent
      [Funktionale\\Anforderungen, for tree={child, fill=col3}
        [Lerninhalte\\organisieren, tier=first]
        [Lerninhalte\\erstellen]
        [Lerninhalte\\abfragen]
        [Kommunikation]
        [Benutzerkonten-\\führung]
        [Steuerungs-\\funktionen]
      ]
      [, tier=first, my phantom
        [Nicht-Funktionale\\Anforderungen, tier=second, for tree={child, fill=col2}
          [Zuverl{\"a}ssig\-keit, tier=third]
          [Skalierbar\-keit\\und Effizienz]
          [Benutzer-\\freundlich\-keit]
          [Portierbarkeit]
          [Datenschutz\\/ Informa-\\tionssicherheit]
          [Erweiterbar\-keit]
          [Anpassbarkeit]
          [, my phantom, tier=third
            [Technische\\Rahmen-\\bedinungen, for tree={child, calign=last, fill=col1}
              [System\-architektur]
              [Software\-kriterien]
              [Schnittstellen]
              [Wartung\\und Support
                [Support\-leistungen]
                [Software-Pflege]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

## EDIT

The above works fine for me inside `\resizebox...`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
%Defining tikz classes for tree diagrams
\forestset{%
  parent/.style={text width=3cm,rounded corners=3pt},
  child/.style={rounded corners=3pt},
  my phantom/.style={inner xsep=0pt, draw=none, child anchor=children}
}
\colorlet{col1}{white}
\colorlet{col2}{gray!20}
\colorlet{col3}{gray!40}
\colorlet{col4}{gray!60}

\begin{document}
  \resizebox*{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{forest}
    forked edges,
    for tree={
        draw,
        rounded corners,
        align=center,
        text centered,
        minimum height=1.5cm,
        parent anchor=children,
        anchor=parent,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      where n children=0{}{%
        if content={}{}{%
          text width=27mm
        },
      },
    },
    [LMS, fill=col4, parent
      [Funktionale\\Anforderungen, for tree={child, fill=col3}
        [Lerninhalte\\organisieren, tier=first]
        [Lerninhalte\\erstellen]
        [Lerninhalte\\abfragen]
        [Kommunikation]
        [Benutzerkonten-\\führung]
        [Steuerungs-\\funktionen]
      ]
      [, tier=first, my phantom
        [Nicht-Funktionale\\Anforderungen, tier=second, for tree={child, fill=col2}
          [Zuverl{\"a}ssig\-keit, tier=third]
          [Skalierbar\-keit\\und Effizienz]
          [Benutzer-\\freundlich\-keit]
          [Portierbarkeit]
          [Datenschutz\\/ Informa-\\tionssicherheit]
          [Erweiterbar\-keit]
          [Anpassbarkeit]
          [, my phantom, tier=third
            [Technische\\Rahmen-\\bedinungen, for tree={child, calign=last, fill=col1}
              [System\-architektur]
              [Software\-kriterien]
              [Schnittstellen]
              [Wartung\\und Support
                [Support\-leistungen]
                [Software-Pflege]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}}
\end{document}
```

[image: resized]

Adding `calign with current` to `Anpassbarkeit`:

```
          [Anpassbarkeit, calign with current]
```

produces

[image: realigned]

Comment: thanks again @cfr! I also was wondering if `calign` could align a particular node (beside the first and the last and the middle)? Unfortunately I couldn't find an example for aligning any node inbetween. you know what I mean? Then I could save even more space if I align the childs of `Nicht-Funktionale Anforderungen` with the 7th. node for instance.

Comment: uhh, I just used your code in `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{` which totally went crazy... (especially with the phantom nodes) I remember you told not to do this for the reason of text issues, but I need to fit my diagram into my page. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Actually, I do it sometimes, too. I just felt I had to say it is not recommended ;). (Which it isn't, but sometimes I do what's not recommended.) I'll try this. I've not had a problem before so didn't think to test this.

Comment: @Eric It works OK for me. Please see edit above. I don't see any difference except that it makes everything a bit smaller, of course.

Comment: okay this is confusing. I added a picture of my output above. Do you have any idea where this could come from? Or at least how I could start debugging this? :D And would you also have an idea how I could align `Anpassbarkeit` with its parent `Nicht-Funktionale Anforderungen`? Then I could go another way to save some space.

Comment: For the first, see comment above. For the second, try adding `calign with current edge` or `calign with current` to `Anpassbarkeit`.

Comment: @Eric Please see edit. I take it you had something like that in mind?

Comment: this is great, yes. Thus, text is better readable! The linespacing is very big still. Not in my test-doc but in my productive document. And `Nicht-Funktionale Anforderungen` writes over the border. Any ideas where this could come from? see the picture in my edit above, pls.

Comment: @Eric Without knowing the code, it is really hard to say. Maybe you are using a different font or font size in your document. But, I mean, I can only guess.

Comment: Good guess! It was the font size... at least for the overfull box. I am using 11pt. But why is forest not automatically increasing the boxes? there is no max-width, isn't it? Regarding the line-spacing are there any options to regulate manually?

Comment: The code contains `text width` specifications in `mm` so they won't scale with the font size. (I think they were `cm` in the original - I tend to prefer `mm` so I don't have to worry about losing decimal points.) For the line spacing, these are basically tabulars so you can always say `\\[<dimension>]` with a negative dimension, as you can in `tabular` environments normally.